# pandas pivot regression analysis

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, regression

I have a dataset similar to:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
dat = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data

results = []
def fit_model_and_get_results(formula, data):
    model = smf.ols(formula, data=data).fit()
    #print(model.summary())
    this_run = {}
    this_run['model'] = formula

    model_df = model.summary2().tables[1]
    quality_tables = model.summary2().tables[0]
    quality_tables.columns = [quality_tables.columns % 2, quality_tables.columns // 2]
    quality_tables = quality_tables.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
    quality_tables.columns = ['metric_kind', 'metric_value']
    quality_tables = quality_tables[quality_tables.metric_kind != '']

    for index, row in quality_tables.iterrows():
         this_run[row.metric_kind] = row.metric_value

    for k, v in this_run.items():
         model_df[k] = v
    return model_df


current_result = fit_model_and_get_results('Lottery ~ Literacy', dat)
current_result['variant'] = 'single_variable'
results.append(current_result)

current_result = fit_model_and_get_results('Lottery ~ Crime_pers', dat)
current_result['variant'] = 'single_variable'
results.append(current_result)

current_result = fit_model_and_get_results('Lottery ~ Crime_prop', dat)
current_result['variant'] = 'single_variable'
results.append(current_result)

# ***********************************************************************************
# adjustment for literacy
current_result = fit_model_and_get_results('Lottery ~ Literacy + Crime_pers', dat)
current_result['variant'] = 'two_variables'
results.append(current_result)

current_result = fit_model_and_get_results('Lottery ~ Literacy + Crime_prop', dat)
current_result['variant'] = 'two_variables'
results.append(current_result)

results = pd.concat(results)
#results = results.reset_index()
display(results)
```

which looks like:
[image]
i.e. one variable in the model constitutes and observation and the data frame contains multiple models.

However, to be able to better compare the results I would love to obtain an output similar to:
[image]
where each variable is present once (as a single observation) but multiple models constitute the columns.

It looks like a pivot is required.
However, so far I have not found the right way to perform it.

The desired result should contain:

- the variable as the first column with one row for each variable
- and then each model as a separate column where it is good enough to keep only the regression coefficient, t-value, and p-value

### edit

Multiple regressions should be easily comparable. I.e. once all 1 combinations then some features are adjusted for (sex, gender) and then again all the remaining single combinations with these featured added for adjustment are calculated and then a single 3rd model where all the features are used for prediction.

I.e. in this case first all 1 combinations (Literacy, Crime_pers) are calculated as separate (single) models.
Then, it is adjusted for Literacy and the remaining ones (only Crime_pers) are calculated.
The 3-rd model mentioned above is omitted to keep the example minimal.

As requested an
output sample data frame for the first 2 cases:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['Crime_pers', 'Literacy'], 'single_variable': [[4,4,6],[2,6,3]], 'two_variables' : [
    #coef, t, p
    np.nan,
    [2,3,4]]})
display(d)
print(d)
      feature single_variable two_variables
0  Crime_pers       [4, 4, 6]           NaN
1    Literacy       [2, 6, 3]     [2, 3, 4]
```

Where the sub-columns within each field are (coefficient, t-value, p-value (they currently do not contain the real values just made up values for brevity)).
For record `0`and `two_variables` the output is NaN as only the values for the models which were not explicitly adjusted for are relevant.

Basically the output above shows the results of all the 3 models which were fitted in a very compressed format.

### edit 2

I updated the minimal example as it was too minimalistic.
Unfortunately, I am stuck with:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

when applying the suggested pivot step

Comment: Can you come up with a **minimal** example of what you want?

Comment: I added a minimal output data frame. Is this want you asked for?

Comment: It is not clear what should be in `d` for two_variables: there should be two lists - one for each variable, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Stef: no. A single list (coefficient, t-value, p-value) for each variable is enough. However, sometimes it should be `NAN`, in case the model explicitly controls for a variable. As in the example, the 3-rd model controls for 'Crime_pers' and we model literacy only the output of Literacy is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't get the logic of what to select for the final result table, but maybe this helps you to adapt it as needed:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(results.loc[results.index!='Intercept','variant'])
res['val'] = results.loc[results.index!='Intercept',['Coef.', 'P>|t|', 't']].apply(lambda x: list(map('{:.3f}'.format, list(x))), axis=1)
res = res[(res.index=='Literacy') | (res.variant=='single_variable')].pivot(columns='variant')
```

Result:

```
                                val                         
variant             single_variable            two_variables
Crime_pers    [0.000, 0.981, 0.024]                      NaN
Literacy    [-0.524, 0.001, -3.590]  [-0.525, 0.001, -3.570]
```

Comment: Interesting. This goes pretty far. Why do you: `map('{:.3f}'.format` map it all to string type? Instead of keeping the floats?

Comment: It turns out the example was too minimalistic. I am stuck with duplicate entries in the index - thus the unstack/reshape fails. What can be changed to get this more complex example to work?

Comment: Trying to adapt the index: `res = res.pivot(columns=['variant', 'model'])` fails so far.

Comment: the string conversion is just for better readability, as the floats will be printed with all significant digits by default

Comment: as for the duplicate indexes I can't advise anything as I don't fully understand the underlying logic, but I think you should add an additional variable in your `current_result` lists to tell them apart. I'm afraid I can't advise specifically what variable to include as I don't understand the logic.

Comment: It should be `model `, could you explain/show me how to add it? As I seem to have failed to get this additional variable into your code snippet.

Comment: maybe `res.pivot_table('val', res.index, ['variant', 'model'], lambda x: x)`?  (`res` creation with `res = pd.DataFrame(results.loc[results.index!='Intercept',['variant','model']])`